# Want to use result of one request in a second request, for API testing with Cypress

Tags: mocking, cypress, web-api-testing, cypress-intercept

I want to test API endpoint using cypress and want do mocking for AUTH token because it's coming from another API

```js
cy.intercept({
method:'get',
url:'/first endpoint'
},response).as('mocktoken');

cy.request({
method:'get',
url:'/firstendpoint'}).then(response=>{
 cy.request({
method:'get',
url:'/secondendpoint'}).then(response=>{ // assertion statement});
```

Thhis is not working what can be done to implement this scenario

First, i want auth token from first which I am, trying to mock then using this token I will get the response from second endpoint

Comment: Cypress will not intercept any requests sent via `cy.request`. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Verifying-the-request-modification -> `cy.intercept() cannot be debugged using cy.request()! Cypress only intercepts requests made by your front-end application.`

Comment: What are you testing if you mock the request to get a auth token when could you not set the data instead?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `cy.intercpet()` in this case, it's for intercepting web page requests not test requests.

This is how you can do it most simply

```js
cy.request('/firstendpoint')
  .then(response1 => {
    cy.request({
      method:'get',
      url:'/secondendpoint',
      body: {
        token: response1.token    // check where the token is in the response
      }
    })
    .then(response2 => { 
      ...
    })
  })
```

There is no mocking, you are using the real thing!

Comment: The first endpoint is unacceble. So trying to mock response (auth token)  for it. Any other way of doing it.

Comment: what can be use to catch request made without the web page

Comment: what does to token look like?